# Issue in printing brought-forward and carry-forward totals in BI Publisher

Tags: bi-publisher

We are developing a BI Publisher invoice print report using RTF layout. This report prints the customer details at the top of the page, followed by the invoice lines' details, and a summary table (of amounts and taxes) at the bottom of the page. Brought-forward are carry-forward totals are displayed at the top and bottom of each page (in case of multi-page reports).It is important to maintain the consistency of the print format (so that the customer address is always at the top left corner of the page, summary table is always printed at the bottom etc). To print the summary at the bottom of the page for each invoice, we have used the  tag with section break, as recommended in the user guide. This works fine in situations when the invoice has multiple lines spilling over to the second page.

However, we are facing an issue in a particular scenario : Invoice has few lines that fit in the first page itself, but there is no space left to print the summary table in the same page , so the summary table alone is printed in the second page at the bottom. In this case the carry-forward total in page 1 and the brought-forward total in page 2 are not being displayed. If you have observed a similar issue anytime please suggest how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider separating your sections and not using Word's header and footer.

Place this code at the start of your document

```
<?initial-page-number:'1'?>
<?call-template:tHEADER_VERSO?>
<?start:body?>
    <?call-template:tHEADER_RECTO?>
    <?call-template:tCONTACT?>
    <?for-each@section:On_Payment_Terms_S3?>
        <?call-template:tDETAILS?>
    <?end for-each?>
<?end body?>
<?call-template:FOOTER?>
```

Then to define a section

```
<?template:tFOOTER?>
insert content here
<?end template?>
```

That way the document will always preserve enough space to print your carry-forward totals. I experienced the same odds results when you put your carry-forward in the Word's footer.